# How do I clone a model field in another model in Django?

Tags: django

```
class Medicine(models.Model):
    medicine_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=30)

class Bill(models.Model):
    regid = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    medicine_name = models.ForeignKey(Medicine)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

What I want is to have a 'price' field in the 'Bill' model and the value of 'price' field should be same as the value of 'price' field in 'Medicine' model based on 'medicine_name'

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to copy it rather than reference it. So that if in future price of medicine changes, past bills does not change.

So you can add a similar field in `Bill` and implement [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal to put same price as medicine object.

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    regid = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    medicine_name = models.ForeignKey(Medicine)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=30)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Bill, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
def signal_price_populate(sender, **kwargs):
    try:
        inst = kwargs['instance']
        inst.price = inst.machine_name.price
    except Exception:
        #something not right
```

Comment: Rohan is right. What you need is a copy of, not reference to, the price. Any changes to the price of a medicine in the future should not affect existing bills that has that medicine.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I am new to Django framework. Do I have to write this code in models.py file?

Comment: @user1676038, yes you can put that in models.py

Comment: this doesn't work. Actually what I want is to have a model whose 'price' fied will automatically take values from 'price' field of Medicine model for a particular medicine name

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have Medicine as a ForeignKey you could access the price through this relationship. ie.

```
medicine_name__price
```

However, if you want a field directly linked to the value of price then you can use a further specification of a ForeignKey.

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    regid = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    medicine_name = models.ForeignKey(Medicine)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, to_field="price")
```

**UPDATE after more info:**

If you are wanting to set the price field in the Bill model based on the price value in the Medicine model on save of the Bill model you could either do this at the save of the model or of the form. This is assuming that your medicine_name foreignkey is working properly so that we can call the value of the price through this relationship.

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    regid = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    medicine_name = models.ForeignKey(Medicine)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=30)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price = self.medicine_name.price
        super(Bill, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Actually what I want is to have a model whose 'price' fied will automatically take values from 'price' field of Medicine model for a particular medicine name

Comment: The to_field doesn't work? Are you wanting it to retrieve the price on save of the Bill?

Comment: yes..i want to retrieve the price on save of bill. I have excluded the  'price' field in the forms.py file

Comment: I updated my response according to what I think you are looking for.  would usually prefer to do this at the form save level, but since I didn't have your form code and didn't know if you are using function of class-based views I put the model save version.